# How to popup a new view on top of a UISplitView

Tags: ipad, popup, uisplitview

I have a split view based iPad application. I need to popup a new view that takes over full screen. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to read up on the [View-Controller programming paradigm](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) apple uses.  You may need to look at popping up a modal controller to take over the screen, use

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Yeah, I am very familiar with MVC. I use it all the time with Java based projects. I am new to iPad/Objective-C development. So my question is a little more specific. I am actually using the presentModalViewController right now, but there is a problem when using the full screen presentation style. It seems like it get's it's coordinates all messed up. It draws inside the detail view when in landscape mode. The end result I want is to completely hide the split view with a new view.

Thanks though. That was close.